# Crashing on negative input Haskell

Tags: haskell

Can anyone explain why this crashes upon negative input?

```
add :: Integral a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
add f n | n<0  = error "only non-negative integers allowed as input"
    | otherwise     = sum[ f x |x<-[1..n] ]


foo:: Int -> Int
foo x = x
```

---

```
*Main> add foo -5

<interactive>:82:9:
No instance for (Num (Int -> Int))
arising from a use of `-'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (Int -> Int))
In the expression: add foo - 5
In an equation for `it': it = add foo - 5
```

Comment: Technically, your program is not crashing. You are just getting a compilation error.

Comment: Yes the program is in fact never being executed, or built for that matter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to write `(-5)` to make clear you're using the unary `-`, otherwise haskell is going to read `-` as the binary operator:

```
add foo (-5)
```